# Why do I have 2 ip addresses on company network?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, ip

I am getting 2 IP addresses on company network(wireless) on my Arch Linux. I am wondering why this situation happens. Company sysadmin doesn't know why either.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:bb:79:63:dd:26 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.213/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 676567sec preferred_lft 676567sec
    inet 192.168.0.178/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 676572sec preferred_lft 590172sec
    inet6 fe80::3b37:5ae7:5189:e354/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::678c:d8c5:cf0b:d555/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have just one IP address as public. I started capture `wlan0` and filtered `dhcp` but I don't know how to interpret packages.

I checked the link from Peregrino69. When I `ls /usr/bin | grep dhcp` i got 5 results `dhcpcd`, `dhcp_lease_time`, `dhcp_release`, `dhcp_release6` and `miracle-dhcp`. But note that I just encounter this issue on company network, no issue on home or any other network.

Comment: Did you ark your sysadmin?

Comment: You've not provided any details so we can only guess. DHCP and Static? Wired and wireless?

Comment: Show us examples ip for public ones, and those private can be pasted as well. There's no sufficient informations. Paste in your original post the output of `ip a`

Comment: Its dhcp and wireless. Sysadmin does not know why, too.

Comment: Try monitoring dhcp/bootp packets on wlan0 with `tcpdump` or `wireshark`.  You'll need to see the entire dhcp request & response chain to make sense of what's going on.  Better yet, your sysadmin should do this on the dhcp server, and/or enable verbose logging in the dhcp daemon (if available) whilst debugging.  They should also be able to search for your MAC address in the dhcp config - maybe it's an error as simple as having two fixed entries for your MAC or something like that. They should `grep -i` for your MAC in the dhcpd logs too.

Comment: An older question regarding the same with a possible solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518735/why-is-my-client-getting-two-ip-addresses-when-connecting-to-wifi

Comment: `Sysadmin does not know why, too` hire a better sys admin

Comment: @cas I started capture wlan0 and filtered dhcp but i dont know how to interpret packages.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I checked link. When i `ls /usr/bin | grep dhcp` i got 5 result `dhcpcd
dhcp_lease_time
dhcp_release
dhcp_release6
miracle-dhcp`. But note that, i just encounter this issue on company network, no issue on home or any other network.

Comment: Rather than answering in comments, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/738811/edit) your question to add new info so everything relevant is readily available. No need now, I've added these comments for you already; my edit will become visible once approved by another member of the community. How to do the Wireshark capture: 1) disconnect from Wi-Fi 2) Start capture 3) Connect to Wi-Fi 4) Wait until 2 IPs 5) Upload the unfiltered capture file to some cloud service and add the link to the question.

Comment: Capture in the morning when you 1st time connect to the company network, and have no other applications running to prevent any data leakage. If you want to filter during the capture, use filter `arp || dhcp || bootp`.